# If $X$ and $Y$ independent and identically distributed, then $E(|X-Y|)\leq E(|X+Y|)$. Are other proofs of this known?

Tags: pr.probability, integration

I know a proof of the theorem that if $X$ and $Y$ independent and identically distributed, then $E(|X-Y|)\leq E(|X+Y|)$. The proof uses an integral representation of the absolute value,
$$\int_0^\infty u^{-2}[1-\cos(au)]\,\mathrm{d}u = \mathrm{constant}\cdot|a|$$
I'm trying to find other proofs.  Does anyone know another one?

Comment: @BrendanMcKay : If $X$ and $Y$ are independent and symmetric about $0$, then $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ have the same distribution. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent and have the same distribution, then there can be no counterexamples, as the answers below show.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Right, my Maple had a stupid bug.  I'll delete the second part of my comment. I'd still be interested in any weakening of the iid restriction.

Comment: For the record, being independent and having mean 0 is not enough. There are examples with $$ and $$ each concentrated at 3 points. What weakening of the iid condition is plausible?

Comment: See my comment to Terry Tao's post below. See also Solution 2 for Problem P.30 in the named book.

Answer (score 35):

Shorn of probabilistic language, this inequality follows from the assertion that $|x+y|-|x-y|$ is a positive semi-definite kernel, and is therefore the sum (or integral) of squares.  Your Fourier-analytic argument gives one such sum-of-squares representation; here is a physical space one.

First observe the identity
$$ |X+Y| - |X-Y| = 2\min(|X|, |Y|) \mathrm{sgn}(X) \mathrm{sgn}(Y)$$
(for instance, one can first check the case $0 \leq Y \leq X$, then observe that the identity is preserved under permutations and sign changes of $X,Y$).  Thus by Fubini's theorem
\begin{align*}
{\bf E} (|X+Y|-|X-Y|) &= 2{\bf E} \min(|X|, |Y|) \mathrm{sgn}(X) \mathrm{sgn}(Y) \\
&= 2\int_0^\infty {\bf E} 1_{|X| \geq t} 1_{|Y| \geq t} \mathrm{sgn}(X) \mathrm{sgn}(Y)\ dt \\
&= 2\int_0^\infty |{\bf E} 1_{|X| \geq t} \mathrm{sgn}(X)|^2\ dt \\
&\geq 0.
\end{align*}

This is assuming that $X,Y$ are real-valued.  I'm not sure what happens in the complex (or vector-valued) case.

UPDATE: In the paper of Buja et al. referenced in Iosif's answer there is a standard trick to get from the real scalar case to the (real or complex) vector-valued case, which is to note that for any vector $X$, the magnitude $\| X \|$ is proportional to ${\bf E} |\langle X, u \rangle|$ where $u$ is a random unit vector.  For instance, if $z$ is a complex number, then $|z| = \frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^1 |\mathrm{Re} z e^{-2\pi i \theta}|\ d\theta$.  One can now derive the vector-valued inequality ${\bf E} \|X-Y\| \leq {\bf E} \|X+Y\|$ by applying the scalar inequality to obtain ${\bf E} |\langle X-Y, u \rangle| \leq {\bf E} |\langle X+Y, u \rangle|$ for every unit vector $u$ and then averaging.

Comment: This argument is essentially the same as Solution 1 of Problem P.30 in Székely (ed.): Contests in Higher Mathematics - Miklós Schweitzer Competitions (1962-1991). The problem was the 10th problem in the 1990 contest.

Answer (score 18):

It suffices to prove that for arbitrary $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ we have
$$\sum_{i, j} |X_i-X_j|\leqslant \sum_{i, j} |X_i+X_j|, 
\quad \quad \quad (\star)$$
then applying $(\star)$ for a random sample from your distribution and taking the expectation you get what you need with extra term which is $O(1/n)$, so in the limit exactly what you need.

Proving $(\star)$ may be done by many ways, for example by induction: the base cases $n=0,n=1$ are easy, for $n>1$ you may replace all $X_i$'s by $X_i+t$ and optimise by $t$. The left hand side is not changed, the right hand side is piecewise linear, thus the minimum is attained when one of terms is 0,that means $X_i=-X_j$ (possibly with $i=j$). Then you may safely remove these $X_i, X_j$, and both left and right hand side are changed by the same value. So you may proceed by induction.

For $\sqrt{|X-Y|}$ and $\sqrt{|X+Y|}$ the inequality like $(\star)$ was proposed at IMO 2021. Above is a modified the most standard solution of this problem.

Answer (score 16):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$In Theorem 2.3 of [Buja, Logan, Reeds, and Shepp](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-22/issue-1/Inequalities-and-Positive-Definite-Functions-Arising-from-a-Problem-in/10.1214/aos/1176325376.full), it was shown  by a modification of a method of [Lévy](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Theorie_de_l_Addition_des_Variables_Alea/_QFzuwEACAAJ?hl=en) (Lemma 2.2 by Buja etal, with a proof like that in another answer) that the function $\R^n\times\R^n\ni(x,y)\mapsto\|x+y\|_q^p-\|x-y\|_q^p$ is positive definite if $q\in[1,2]$ and $p\in(0,q]$, where $\|\cdot\|_q$ is the $q$-norm on $\R^n$. It follows that
$$E\|X-Y\|_q^p\le E\|X+Y\|_q^p, \tag{2}\label{2}$$
for such $p$ and $q$, where $X$ and $Y$ are independent identically distributed (iid) random vectors in $\R^n$.

---

A one-line proof,
$$E|X+Y|-E|X-Y|=2\int_0^\infty[P(X>r)-P(X<-r)]^2\,dr,$$
of \eqref{2} for $n=p=q=1$ was given on p. 74 of the paper by [Lifshits, Schilling, and Tyurin](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-0348-0490-5_5), who also gave various generalizations of \eqref{2}, including the following:
$$E\psi(X-Y)\le E\psi(X+Y), \tag{3}\label{3}$$
where $\psi\colon\R^n\to\R$ is any continuous negative definite function and $X$ and $Y$ are iid random vectors in $\R^n$. They also showed a connection with bifractional Brownian motion.

---

[Corollary 5](https://www-tandfonline-com.services.lib.mtu.edu/doi/abs/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.123.5.491) states the following: For any two-dimensional normed space $V$ and any iid random vectors $X$ and $Y$ in $V$ we have
$$E\|X−Y\|≤E\|X+Y\|.$$
This inequality is based on (an explicit version of) the well-known result by Lindenstrauss that any two-dimensional normed space can be isometrically imbedded into $L^1(0,1)$.

---

The inequality in the title of your post also admits the following generalization:
$$E\|X-Y\|^p\le E\|X+Y\|^p,$$
for any $p\in(0,2]$, where $X$ and $Y$ are iid random vectors in a separable Hilbert space with norm $\|\cdot\|$.

This follows immediately from  [Corollary 2.2](https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.04391), which is a certain generalization of the integral representation of the absolute value in your post, and Theorem 4.1 in the same paper.

Comment: Can you infer a complex version from any of this?

Comment: @BrendanMcKay : One can identify $\mathbb C$ (with the norm being the modulus) with $\mathbb R^2$ (with the Euclidean norm), and then $\mathbb C^n$ (with the appropriate norm) with $\mathbb R^{2n}$ ((with the Euclidean norm).

Comment: Your second display says the same as the second display in Terry's post.

Comment: @GHfromMO : Thank you for your comment. I did not notice that. The paper by Lifshits, Schilling, and Tyurin of 2013 does not give any references to this one-line proof. Anyhow, this proof first appeared in or before 2013.

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$[Pinelis](https://mathoverflow.net/a/437610/498930) mentions the result
$$E[\psi(X-Y)] \le E[\psi(X+Y)], \tag{3'}\label{3'}$$
where $\psi\colon\R^n\to\R$ is any continuous negative definite function and $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. random vectors in $\R^n$. This is a special case of a more general result: Let $X, Y, X', Y'$ be independent with $(X, Y)$ and $(X', Y')$
having the same law. Then $$E[\psi(X - X')] + E[\psi(Y - Y')] \le 2 E[\psi(X - Y)];\tag{4}\label{4}$$ this is just the definition of negative definite when $(X, Y)$ takes only finitely many values, and the general case follows by approximation. Apply this to $Y$ having the law of $-X$ to get \eqref{3'}.

Thus, \eqref{4} implies \eqref{3'}. The converse is not quite true. [Gao](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-26391-1_5) proves that if \eqref{3'} holds and $\psi$ is continuous and polynomially bounded, then $\psi$ is negative definite, whence \eqref{4} holds. [[2](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-26391-1_5)] also  gives a counterexample where \eqref{3'} holds but $\psi$ is *not* negative definite (so \eqref{4} fails), namely, $\psi(x) := e^{\|x\|}$.

More generally, if $X, X', Y, Y'$ above have values in a separable
premetric space $(M, d)$, then $(M, d)$ is said to have *negative type* if
$$E[d(X,X')] + E[d(Y,Y')] \le 2 E[d(X,Y)].\tag{5}\label{5}$$
For \eqref{4}, we can use the premetric on $\R^n$ to be $d(x, y) := \psi(x-y) - \psi(0)$. Suppose that \eqref{5} holds and $E[d(X, x_0) + d(Y, x_0)]< \infty$ for some $x_0 \in M$. If equality in \eqref{5} holds iff $X$ and $Y$ have the same law, then we say $(M, d)$ has *strong negative type*. For sketches of four proofs that $\R^n$ has negative type with its usual metric and one proof of the equality condition, see [Distance covariance in metric spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.5758), where it is also proved that Hilbert space has strong negative type. The equality condition is crucial for applications in statistics. Negative type metric spaces have a beautiful theory and have important applications in computer science; sometimes the theory is used in the form of a kernel and a reproducing kernel Hilbert space.

To understand the genesis of some of these ideas, note that \eqref{4} with $\psi(x) = \|x\|$ becomes trivial if $\psi(x) = \|x\|^2$ were used instead, in which case the equality condition becomes that $E[X] = E[Y]$. Schoenberg proved that negative type for a separable premetric space $(M, d)$ is equivalent to the existence of an isometric embedding of $(M, \sqrt{d})$ into Hilbert space; [[3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.5758)] gives a sketch of the proof. Whenever a semimetric $d$ has negative type, then $d^\alpha$ has strong negative type for all $\alpha \in (0, 1)$; see [[3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.5758), Remark 3.19]. In particular, equality holds in \eqref{3'} for $\psi(x) = \|x\|^p$ ($0 < p < 2$) iff the law of $X$ is symmetric by reflection in the origin.

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow, Russ