# An inequality for two iid r.v.s

Tags: probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are iid, show that  $P(|X+Y|<1) \leq 3 P(|X-Y|<1)$.

Comment: [Maybe relevant](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437581/if-x-and-y-independent-and-identically-distributed-then-ex-y-leq-ex).

Comment: If you want a direct proof, split the line into half-open intervals of length $1$ and use Cauchy-Schwarz. Anyway, it looks like a typical homework in graduate probability course, so I naturally wonder if it is...

Comment: Yes, it is a problem in the probability theory exercise class, and it is also a problem  of S.-T YAU COLLEGE MATH CONTESTS 2012.

Answer (score 4):

Let $x_n=\mathbb{P}(n<X\leq n+1)$, then
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(|X-Y|<1)\geq \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathbb{P}(n<X\leq n+1)\mathbb{P}(n<Y\leq n+1)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}x_n^2,
\end{align*}
and thus
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(|X+Y|<1)\leq \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathbb{P}(n<X\leq n+1)\mathbb{P}(-n-2<Y\leq -n+1)\\ =\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}x_n(x_{-n-2}+x_{-n-1}+x_{-n})\leq 3\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}x_n^2\leq 3\mathbb{P}(|X-Y|<1).
\end{align*}

Comment: Very nice proof!

Answer (score 3):

This is an instance of the "*123-theorem*": for any $0<a\leq b$ and i.i.d. real random variables $X,Y$, it holds that
$$P(|X+Y|\leq b)\leq \lceil{2b/a}\rceil P(|X-Y|\leq a),$$
$$P(|X-Y|\leq b)\leq (\lceil{2b/a}\rceil-1) P(|X-Y|\leq a).$$

So for $a=b=1$ we have
$$P(|X+Y|\leq 1)\leq 2P(|X-Y|\leq 1),$$
which is stronger than the inequality in the OP.

For a proof, see

1. [The 123
   Theorem and Its Extension](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/123.pdf), N. Alon and R. Yuster (1995).
2. [A Note on Distribution-Free Symmetrization Inequalities](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.1243), Z. Dong, J. Li, and W.V. Li (2015).
3. [The 123 theorem of Probability
   Theory and Copositive Matrices,](https://eudml.org/doc/267310) A. Kovačec, M.R. Moreira, and
   D.P. Martins (2014).

<sub>The name "123-theorem" refers to the special case $P(|X-Y|\leq 2)\leq 3 P(|X-Y|\leq 1)$. There is a [German Wikipedia page,](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/123-Theorem) it might deserve an English version...</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the conclusion in the three references is so general and thus the proof is not direct, I want to know is there a direct proof?